# MySQL UPDATE with SUBQUERY of same table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am working with a complex MySQL database table that collects form data. I have simplified the layout in an example table called **test** below:

```
|FormID|FieldName|  FieldValue |
|   1  |   city  |   Houston   |
|   1  | country |     USA     |
|   2  |   city  |   New York  |
|   2  | country |United States|
|   3  | property|   Bellagio  |
|   3  |  price  |     120     |
|   4  |   city  |   New York  |
|   4  |zip code |    12345    |
|   5  |   city  |   Houston   |
|   5  | country |     US      |
```

Through phpMyAdmin I need to make global updates to some tables, specifically I want to *update* all **FieldValue** entries to "United States of America" with the **FieldName** "country" that have the same **FormID** as the **FieldName** "city" and the **FieldValue** "Houston".

I can easily *display* these entries with a SELECT statement by either using a SUBQUERY or by using an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT FieldValue
FROM test
WHERE FormID
IN (
   SELECT FormID
   FROM test
   WHERE FieldName =  "city"
   AND FieldValue =  "Houston"
   )
AND FieldName =  "country"
```

Or:

```
SELECT a.FieldValue
FROM test a
INNER JOIN test b ON a.FormID = b.FormID
WHERE a.FieldName = "country"
AND b.FieldName = "city"
AND b.FieldValue = "Houston"
```

However I try to compose my **UPDATE** statement I get some form of MySQL-error indicating that I cannot reference the same table in either a **subquery** or **inner join** or **union** scenario. I have even created a **view** and tried to reference this in the update statement, but no resolve.
Does anyone have any idea how to help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: Can you pick an answer or precise your needs ?

Answer (score 39):

You have to use a temporary table, because you can't update something you use to select. A simple exemple:

This will not working :

```
UPDATE mytable p1 SET p1.type= 'OFFER' WHERE p1.parent IN 
    (SELECT p2.id from mytable p2 WHERE p2.actu_id IS NOT NULL);
```

This will do the job:

```
UPDATE mytable p1 SET p1.type= 'OFFER' WHERE p1.parent IN 
    (SELECT p2.id from (SELECT * FROM mytable) p2 WHERE p2.actu_id IS NOT NULL);
```

"from (SELECT * FROM mytable) p2" will create a temporary duplicate of your table, wich will not be affected by your updates

Comment: MYSQL 5.7.9 (Wampserver 3 64 bit) didn't buy the trick, it still complains about using the same table for update and select, I even added another inner "select *" but still doesn't work.

Comment: @jose : Can you post your request ?

Answer (score 16):

Aliasing should do the trick, if I'm understanding correctly:

```
UPDATE test AS a
JOIN test AS b ON a.id = b.id
    SET a.name = 'New Name'
WHERE a.id = 104;
```

Is this not working for you?
**UPDATE**: This was tested and works on MySQL v5.6.

Comment: Version I checked was 5.5.50, maybe something was fixed.

Comment: What's the purpose of joining to the same table if you did not filter anything?
Isn't your script just the same as
UPDATE test AS a
SET a.name = 'New Name'
WHERE a.Id = 104;?