# Update post_meta value based on 2 keys - Wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 5000+ products in WooCommerce and I'm looking for a SQL query to set their barcodes based on their SKU. Both "barcode" and "sku" are custom posts meta. Basically, something like:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET barcode='x' WHERE sku='y';
```

But it doesn't work because barcode and sku are not real table columns. So, can anyone provide a working query? I'm new to SQL. Thank you!

Comment: How you will set barcode and sku ? because each product must have different once.

Comment: Are you executing these one at a time? Obviously the sku and barcode are two separate rows in wp_postmeta, linked by post_id, but [mysql won't let you query the table you're updating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10359534/243245) e.g. `UPDATE wp_postmeta ... WHERE post_id = (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE ...`. So you may have to run two queries: one to look up the post_id from meta_key='sku' and meta_value='y', and then one to update wp_postmeta where meta_key='barcode' and post_id is the one you've just found.

Comment: @dipmala I have an excel file with all the SKUs and barcodes (unique for each product, of course). I would just copy-paste them into the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sku and barcode will be stored in two separate rows linked by post_id. This is the syntax you'll need to use to update one row based on another in the same table in MySQL ([borrowed from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10359935/243245)):

```
UPDATE  wp_postmeta a
  JOIN  wp_postmeta b on b.post_id = a.post_id
  SET   a.meta_value = 'y'
  WHERE a.meta_key = 'barcode'
    AND b.meta_key = 'sku'
    AND b.meta_value = 'x';
```

i.e. query the ID on table alias b and then update the barcode on table alias a.

(but I don't have a WooCommerce installation to test this on - please backup your DB first! etc.)