# You can't specify target table (UPDATE on SELECT Query )?

Tags: mysql, database

Query :

```
UPDATE `master_customer`  
SET `customer_group_id` = 19 
WHERE `customer_code` IN( SELECT * 
                          FROM `master_customer` a,
                               `master_customer_group` b
                          WHERE a.`customer_group_id` = b.`id`
                            AND b.`id` = 8);
```

Result:

> Query: `` UPDATE `master_customer` SET `customer_group_id` = 19 WHERE `customer_code` IN( SELECT a.`customer_code` FROM `master_customer` ... ``
>
> Error Code: 1093
>      You can't specify target table 'master_customer' for update in FROM clause

Comment: You can see here https://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery

Answer (score 0):

It is a MySQL feature. You can work it around by wrapping subquery to yet another subquery :)

```sql
UPDATE `master_customer`  SET `customer_group_id` = 19 WHERE `customer_code` IN( 
SELECT x.customer_code FROM (
SELECT a.customer_code FROM
    `master_customer` a,
    `master_customer_group` b
    WHERE
    a.`customer_group_id` = b.`id`
    AND b.`id` = 8) AS x
)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33607415/272885